# Monitor android application for user debug

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, crashlytics-android

I wish to monitor app behavior and debug application on different devices.
I am trying to select the best approach, Firebase analytics, crashlitics, Goole analytics etc...

**The problem:**
User report on some devices they see incorrect app behavior (Not crash). For example user reports button not working, I wish to check if the user actually clicked the button and what happened.

**What I need:**
I need to find that specific user (or phone) in the monitoring system mentioned above and check the logs I added (for example: firebaseAnalytics.logEvent...)

**Solution questions**
Can I find specific user or phone in firebaseAnalytics? What is the best approach to addressing my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase Analytics Event Logging & Set User Id.

With this feature, you can keep track of users' logs, later generate statistics in Firebase Analytics or Google Analytics, and track specific users if you wish.

check this links

[Firebase Analytics Set User Id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid)

[Firebase Analytics Event Logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android)

And If you want check not you wanted situation, you can add a custom exception to firebase.

try like this code.

```
if(isExpectedSituation) {
    // some your codes.
} else {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(YourCustomException());
}
```